# Android studio can't file opend and build log nothing to show

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze

[android studio nothing to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1topT.png)

Build, event log, etc. Content is not displayed.
If double-click the file the path changes, but you can't view the file.

I did something like this.

1. reboot android studio/reboot windows
2. reinstall android studio
3. file -> cache / restart
4. Create a new project

But there is still a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your android studio not opening properly after updated. Just open C drive (show hidden files). now you can see the .local file. now go to remove the google file from there. (Path -> local/share/google).